# 2D dynamic modelling of branched cellular aggregates?

Tags: dynamic, model, 2d, cell, bioinformatics

I'm trying to model the behavior of the organism. I would like to represent this model visually, as branched 2D filaments of cells.

I have two variables I'd like to represent on the cells themselves ('age', which increases with time but is reset by a branching event; 'differentiation', which to some extent occurs probabilistically ), ideally with straightforward schemes such as size/color, or size/shape etc.

Said values also affect parameters such as division rate and branching rate.

Could someone recommend a program (ideally free) that I could use for this purpose, please?

Comment: Please provide reproducible data, and expected plot, maybe consider using R? It has many graphing packages, for example [see here](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/). And it is free.